# If $U =\{ f \in P_3| f(-1)=f(1)=0\}$ Then is $P_3 = U⊕P_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

I know that I want to be able to show that $U\cap P_2= \{0\}$ I was able to work out that given the conditions, an element of U should be of the form $ax^3 + bx^2 -ax -b$. Is this correct? If so, how do I proceed from here?

Comment: In the definition of $U$, where you have written $f\in U$, did you mean $f\in P_3$?

Comment: Yes! I've edited it

Answer (score 0):

This is not true.

If $a=0$ and say $b=1$ then you have a polynomial $p(x)=x^2-1\in U$ which is also in $P_2$, so $U\cap P_2\ne \{0\}$

Comment: what if it was $P_1$ instead of $P_2$? Then the intersection WOULD be zero, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: But P3=U⊕P1 would still be false right? Because if both a and b are zero, then 0 ⊕P1 would not include any elements of $P_3$ with degree 2 or 3

Comment: If that would be $P_1$ instead of $P_2$ then the statemnt would be true.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying

Comment: $U$ has dimension 2, $P_1$ has dimension 2, $U\cap P_1=\{0\}$, so $U\oplus P_1$ has dimension 4. It's a subspace of $P_3$, which also has dimension 4, so it equals $P_4$.

Comment: Why does U have dimension 2?

Comment: Also for example, how would you write $p(x)=x^3$ as a direct sum of $P_1$ and U? And when you say 'it's a subspace of $P_3$ which also has dimension 4 so it equals $P_4$', did you mean it equals $P_3$? because $P_4$ would have dimension 5

Comment: You know why $U$ has dimension 2 – you know the elements of $U$ are those of the form $a(x^3-x)+b(x^2-1)$, so you have a basis there for $U$, a basis with two elements.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant $P_3$ when I wrote $P_4$. $x^3-x$ is in $U$, and $x$ is in $P_1$.

Comment: So, 140161, everything OK now?

Comment: Earth to 140161, come in, please.